# "Called object 'int' is not a function or a function pointer" error

Tags: c++, macos, xcode5

Ok, so I'm pretty new and inexperienced so this question is most likely stupid but I tried to look up a solution and failed so I figure I'd try here why not.

I'm trying to write a program that takes the sides of a triangle and outputs the area, perimeter, and whether or not it's a right triangle or not. The perimeter works fine but when I try and define s and the area it gives me the error message "Called object 'int' is not a function or a function pointer"

So this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//area = sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))

int main()
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int perimeter;
int area;
int s;


//ask for triangle sides
cout << "Input triangle sides (smallest to largest) " << endl;
cin >> a >> b >> c;

perimeter = a + b + c;

s =(a+b+c)/2;

area = sqrt(s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c))


//This one says 'Expression is not assignable' I don't see why it wouldn't work...

if ((c*c)-((a*a)+(b*b))= 0 )
    cout << "Right triangle" << endl; 




cout << "Side A: " << a << endl;
cout << "Side B: " << b << endl;
cout << "Side C: " << c << endl;
cout << "The perimeter is " << perimeter << endl;
cout << "The area is " << area << endl;



return 0;
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You know the difference between `=` vesus `==`?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to write `*` explicitly:

   `area = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));`

You have also forgoten the `;` at the end.

1. You probably need `==` for comparison (+ you can drop extra parenthases):

   `if ( c*c - a*a - b*b == 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

No implicit multiplication in C++: use `sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike conventional mathematical notation, multiplication isn't implicit in C++. To multiply numbers, use the * operator

```
area = sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in maths, multiplication always needs a "*" and equality testing is done with "==, not "=".

You should read a decent book.